# Get result from Multiple Select statement on a single Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will display the result of users managed by a manager. I have tried to use CTE but still was unsuccessful.

What I want,

1. The first query to select the row whose `user name = @name`
2. Second query: return users that are managed by (first query `ManagerId`)
3. Third query: return all users that are managed by each (second query `ManagerId`)

This is the structure of the data:

[image]

SQL query:

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS 
(
    (SELECT UserId, Email, ManagerId, Name 
     FROM Table1
     WHERE DisplayName LIKE '%Paul%') tbl1
    (SELECT UserId, Email, ManagerId, Name
     FROM Table1
     WHERE ManagerId = tbl1.UserId) tbl2
    (SELECT UserId, Email, ManagerId, Name
     FROM Table1
     WHERE ManagerId = tbl1.UserId) tbl3
 
)
--Lastly 
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeCTE
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply need a proper **recursive** CTE - something like this:

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS 
(
    -- "anchor" for the query 
    SELECT 
        UserId, Email, ManagerId, Name,
        [Level] = 1
    FROM   
        dbo.Table1
    WHERE 
        Name LIKE '%Paul%'
        -- I would personally probably use this condition instead
        -- ManagerId IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    
    -- recursive part
    SELECT 
        t1.UserId, t1.Email, t1.ManagerId, t1.Name,
        e.[Level] + 1
    FROM   
        dbo.Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
        EmployeeCTE e ON t1.ManagerId = e.UserId
)
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeCTE
```

This selects the "anchor" row (or rows), and then "recurses" the manager/employee relationship based on `Employee.ManagerId = Manager.UserId`. I've also added the `Level` column so you see on which level (of the hierarchy) each entry is located - the "anchor" will be level 1, each further level down is incremented by 1.

PS: if you need to limit the returned data set to the root level + max. of 2 levels down, you can use the `Level` column to do so in your final `SELECT` that selects from the CTE:

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS 
(
   --- as above
)
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeCTE
WHERE [Level] <= 3   -- select root level (1) and max. of 2 levels down
```

Comment: thanks Marc_s, I have tested and re-tested. Your CTE is perfect and really interesting with the use of Level! Now I can play around it well. Day Savor